# Currency formatting using Intl.NumberFormat without currency symbol

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I am trying to use Intl as a default currency formatter and it is almost perfect.

Using the example from a [`Intl.NumberFormat()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat):

```
const number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency',
currency: 'EUR' }).format(number)); // expected output: "123.456,79 €"
 
// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit 
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY'
}).format(number)); // expected output: "￥123,457"
```

This is almost perfect but I would actually like to drop the symbol from the output. So I would expect to see:

```
// expected output: "123.456,79"
// expected output: "123,457"
```

I find it bizarre that I spend over an hour looking for a solution and only found some sort of replace/trim usage.

Why there is not an option to format the number with all the Intl power but only dropping the currency symbol?!?

I hope I missed it, tbh.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One simple way to do achieve what you want is to use [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove the currency from the string. To make this easier, you can set `currencyDisplay` to `"code"` which will use the ISO currency code - the same one passed in to `currency`:

```js
const number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { 
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR', 
    currencyDisplay: "code" 
  })
  .format(number)
  .replace("EUR", "")
  .trim()
); // 123.456,79
 
// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit 
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { 
    style: 'currency', 
   currency: 'JPY', 
    currencyDisplay: "code" 
  })
  .format(number)
  .replace("JPY", "")
  .trim()
); // 123,457
```

This can be extracted into a function:

```js
const number = 123456.789;

console.log(format('de-DE', 'EUR', number)); // 123.456,79
console.log(format('ja-JP', 'JPY', number)); // 123,457

function format (locale, currency, number) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { 
    style: 'currency', 
    currency, 
    currencyDisplay: "code" 
  })
  .format(number)
  .replace(currency, "")
  .trim();
}
```

---

An alternative that allows you more control is to use [`Intl.NumberFormat#formatToParts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts) which formats the number but gives you tokens that you can programmatically consume and manipulate. For example, using the method with `locale = "de-DE"` and `currency = "EUR"` you get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "type": "integer",
    "value": "123"
  },
  {
    "type": "group",
    "value": "."
  },
  {
    "type": "integer",
    "value": "456"
  },
  {
    "type": "decimal",
    "value": ","
  },
  {
    "type": "fraction",
    "value": "79"
  },
  {
    "type": "literal",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "currency",
    "value": "EUR"
  }
]
```

Which means that you can easily filter out `"type": "currency"` and then combine the rest into a string. For example:

```js
const number = 123456.789;

console.log(format('de-DE', 'EUR', number)); // 123.456,79
console.log(format('ja-JP', 'JPY', number)); // 123,457

function format (locale, currency, number) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { 
    style: 'currency',
    currency, 
    currencyDisplay: "code",
  })
  .formatToParts(number)
  .filter(x => x.type !== "currency")
  .filter(x => x.type !== "literal" || x.value.trim().length !== 0)
  .map(x => x.value)
  .join("")
}
```

**NOTE:** the exclusion here: `.filter(x => x.type !== "literal" || x.value.trim().length !== 0)` handles whitespace characters within the number. That might come up when using the option `currencySign: 'accounting'` in the formatter. In some locales this will use parentheses for negative numbers which would leave a space inside if just the currency is removed:

```js
const number = -123456.789;

const parts = new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { 
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'JPY', 
    currencySign: "accounting",
    currencyDisplay: "code",
  })
  .formatToParts(number);
  
console.log(parts); 

/* output:
[
  { type: "literal" , value: "("    },
  { type: "currency", value: "JPY"  },
  { type: "literal" , value: " "    },
  { type: "integer" , value: "123"  },
  { type: "group"   , value: ","    },
  { type: "integer" , value: "457"  },
  { type: "literal" , value: ")"    }
]
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Thus negative numbers are handled correctly:

```js
const number = -123456.789;

console.log(format('de-DE', 'EUR', number)); // 123.456,79
console.log(format('ja-JP', 'JPY', number)); // 123,457

function format (locale, currency, number) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { 
    style: 'currency',
    currency, 
    currencyDisplay: "code",
    currencySign: "accounting",
  })
  .formatToParts(number)
  .filter(x => x.type !== "currency")
  .filter(x => x.type !== "literal" || x.value.trim().length !== 0)
  .map(x => x.value)
  .join("")
}
```

Thanks to [Chris Peckham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842665/chris-peckham) for pointing out potential pitfalls when using the accounting currency sign option.

Comment: Thank you fo looking into it. I understand when you say it might be and odd thing to remove currency but I don't think so. My use case is that I display cost in a table column. I don't want to repeat the symbol in every single cell. I just want to add it to the header. To me formatting and symbol are two different things. Whoever thought about implementing it this way made a mistake in my opinion. At least they should add `currencyDisplay: "none" `

Comment: Yes, I do agree that `currencyDisplay: "none"` makes the most sense. However, (speculating here) the designer might have thought it's not needed because the currency can be removed. Not sure. That is if this was *intentionally* not added. It it might have been an unintentional omission.

Comment: Could you extend your second answer that uses `formatToParts` so that instead of using `trim`, it removes the space literal `{"type":"literal","value":" "}` that follows the currency e.g. `{"type":"currency","value":"EUR"}`?

This would be useful when `{currencySign: 'accounting'}` is used in the `NumberFormat` and trim can't access the space literal because it follows the negative number signifier `'('`

Comment: @ChrisPeckham Much appreciated. I've updated to handle the whitespace better. I was getting a non-breakable space as a literal, so I still used `.trim()` to test for whitespace literals. It should ensure it's not implementation dependant.

Answer (score 3):

**If you only want the separators in between individual digits**, just format as a number instead of using `currency`:

```
const numberFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  // Do not show fractions - front end should only handle whole numbers
  maximumFractionDigits: 0,
});
```

And then `numberFormatter.format(asNumber);` with whatever `number` you like.

For your example of `123456`, `"de-DE"` is `123.456`, `"ja-JP"` is `123,456`

Comment: this is not great because it loses the currency's significant digits. for instance yen does not have cents, so `NumberFormat` would have formatted the value rounded by default.

Comment: also, currencySign: 'accounting' is not available for non-currency styles.